# Understading atomic add and mutex

Tags: go

I'm testing the concurrency of incrementing `itemID` in the handler func below, and sometimes the increment skips a value (example: 4, 6, 7, ... skipped id 5).

```
func proxyHandler() http.Handler {
    var itemID int32
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
        proxy.ModifyResponse = func(res *http.Response) error {
            item := Item{
                ID: int(atomic.AddInt32(&itemID, 1)),
            }
            items.Add(item)
            return nil
        }
        proxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
    })
}
```

I solved it by using Mutex:

```
func proxyHandler() http.Handler {
    itemID := 0
    mux := sync.Mutex{}
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
        proxy.ModifyResponse = func(res *http.Response) error {
            mux.Lock()
            itemID++
            item := Item{
                ID: itemID,
            }
            items.Add(item)
            mux.Unlock()
            return nil
        }
        proxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
    })
}
```

I'd like to understand why atomic add didn't work as I was expecting, that is, generating a sequential value without gaps.

Comment: It could be that `items` (with an `s`) is not synchronized so suddenly, your lock solves this data race. However, I'd like to point out that the `atomic` package is not your issue here. Can you show the definition of `items`?

Comment: items is `var items Items` (which is `type Items []Item`)

Comment: Is it lock protected? If not, then there is your issue. `Items.Add()` should have locking inside of it. Can you post the definition for `Items.Add()`?

Comment: it is not. So the lock in the Add func is enough? I dont understand why

Comment: `func (items *Items) Add(item Item) {
 *items = append(*items, item)
}`

Comment: Slices are not safe for concurrent read/writes in Go. If you put locks inside `Add()` then you wouldn't need to protect write to `itemID` and just use `atomic.AddInt32()`. By the way, your second option is fine. You locked both `itemID` and `items` using `mux`. However `items` is exposed outside of your function so it is possible to have a data race if other goroutines are updating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atomic.AddInt32()` is perfectly fine for concurrent use by multiple goroutines. That is why it is in the `atomic` package. Your issue is with `Items.Add()` which you have pointed out in the comments as not having any lock protection.

This is a rough definition for a safe `Items.Add()`

```
type Items struct {
    items []Item
    lock  sync.Mutex
}

func (i *Items) Add(item Item) {
    i.lock.Lock()
    defer i.lock.Unlock()
    i.items = append(i.items, item)
}
```

With the above definition of `Items`, you can now use your initial code with `atomic.AddInt32()`. However, I would like to point out that you must not read `Items` while other threads are appending to it. Even reads must be synchronized.